# Kotlin fragment if statement issue

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

In my code (in same class) i just call the function like this:

```
menuChange(ClickerFragment())
```

And my function is here:

```
fun menuChange(frag: Fragment){
    if(frag == ClickerFragment()){
        println("Statement worked!")
    }
    println("Function worked!")
}
```

When i run this in console screen, i can see only "Function worked!" text. Idk why if statement not working. But however "frag" is always equal in this case.

Comment: If you didn’t override `equals()` in your ClickerFragment class, then they are not equal because they are distinct instances. Also, typically you don’t want to instantiate an object just to check the values of another unless it’s a small data class.

Comment: @Tenfour04 i just deleted it because i noticed the my real problem was not that. The code is working in MainActivity. Now the problem is about very different from question. So I don't want to stall someone with wrong question.

Comment: But thanks for try help

Answer (score 3):

They can never be equal, because you are creating a new `ClickerFragment()` instance in your if condition.

You should use the `is` operator for checking if an instance is a certain class type:

```kotlin
fun menuChange(frag: Fragment){
    if(frag is ClickerFragment){
        println("Statement worked!")
    }
    println("Function worked!")
}
```

**Documentation**

- [is and !is Operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#is-and-is-operators)

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your check to 
`if(frag is ClickerFragment){`

Answer (score 2):

You need to check instance of fragment instead of equals.
It should like this :

```
fun menuChange(frag: Fragment){
    if(frag is ClickerFragment){
        println("Statement worked!")
    }
    println("Function worked!")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason for `println("Statement worked!")` not working. we are creating the new Instance of the  ClickerFragment() and checking equals (frag) with some other object. which never be true. (we checking both instances are the same). We have check `frag` is a type of `ClickerFragment()`.
This can be achieved by using `is`

```
if(frag is ClickerFragment){
        println("Statement worked!")
    }
```